# Php pdo iterate with sequence

Tags: php, mysql

i want to display question and answers with sequence(first:question then answers) how is it possible?

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "someone";
$password = "someonepassword";
$dbname = "quiz_app";

$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);

$statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM question");
$statement2 = $pdo->prepare("SELECT a.id as answer_id, a.*, 
                                    q.id as question_id, q.* 
                            FROM answer a 
                                inner join question q on a.question_id = q.id");


$statement->execute();
$statement2->execute();


$result = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$result2 = $statement2->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$i=0;
foreach ($result as $row) {
  $i++;
  echo "<h5>".$i.'.'.$row['question_text']. "</h5>";
    foreach ($result2 as $row2) {
      echo "<input name='group". $row2['id'] ."' type='radio' id='". $row2['answer_id'] ."' />" . "<label for='". $row2['answer_id'] ."'>".$row2['answer_text']."</label>";
     }
  echo "<br>";
 }
```

In this code questions and answers are ordered differently(all questions together and after them answers) how can i fix it?

Comment: so do an `ORDER BY col ASC|DESC`?

Comment: ok i got it but it multiplies question_text as number of answers

Comment: See Riggs' answer below.

Comment: *"as number of answers"* - You mean you want to show a "count" for them also? If so, you need to `COUNT()` them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think more logically about the data you are processing. The first query is totally unnecessary, everything you need is in the second query. Just order that by `q.id` and `a.id`

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT q.*,q.id as qid,
                              a.*, a.id as aid
                        FROM question q 
                            inner join answer a on a.question_id = q.id
                        ORDER BY qid, aid");

$q_and_a = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$last_qid = NULL;
foreach ( $q_and_a as $i => $row) {
    if ( $last_qid == $row['qid'] ) {
        // we are starting a new question
        echo "<h5>{$row['question_text']}</h5>";
        $last_qid = $row['qid'];
    }
    // hear we are processing all the answer to the question
    echo "<input name='group{$row2['qid']}' type='radio' id='{$row['aid']}'/>" 
        . "<label for='{$row['aid']}'>{$row['answer_text']}</label>";
}
```

> Not sure if I got the question id and answer id info in the right place in the output, but hopefully this will give you a nudge in the right direction and you can fix any little issues yourself

Comment: Nice to see the green tick. Wasn't sure about OP's comment up there in wanting to possibly add a count for rows, as I stated in comments.

Comment: Now there's another answer... wondering if OP's going to do the "flip flop (green) tick toc" lol am just not a fan of "try this" ;-)

Answer (score 0):

> Try this:

```
<?php

    $servername = "localhost";
    $username   = "someone";
    $password   = "someonepassword";
    $dbname     = "quiz_app";
    $pdo        = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);

    //$sql1       = " SELECT * FROM question ";                 //<== UNNECESSARY QUERY

    $sql2       = " SELECT a.id AS answer_id, a.*, ";
    $sql2      .= " q.id AS question_id, q.* ";
    $sql2      .= " FROM answer a ";
    $sql2      .= " INNER JOIN question q on a.question_id = q.id ";

    //$statement  = $pdo->prepare($sql1);                       //<== UNNECESSARY CODE
    $statement2 = $pdo->prepare($sql2);


    //$statement->execute();                                    //<== UNNECESSARY CODE
    $statement2->execute();


    //$result     = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);     //<== UNNECESSARY CODE
    $result2    = $statement2->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    //$i          = 0;                                          //<== USE THE INDEX OF THE $result2 ARRAY

    $output     = "";                                           //<== BUILD YOUR OUTPUT IN A VARIABLE
    $questions  = "";                                           //<== AN ARRAY OF QUESTIONS.
    foreach ($result2 as $intDex=>$row) {
        $question    = $row['question_text'];
        if(!in_array($question, $questions)){               
            $questions[] = $question;
            $output     .= "<h5>".$i.'.'.$row['question_text']. "</h5>";
            $output     .= "<input name='group". $row2['id'] ."' type='radio' id='". $row2['answer_id'] ."' />";
            $output     .= "<label for='". $row2['answer_id'] ."'>".$row2['answer_text']."</label><br>";
            $output     .= "<br>";
        }else{
            $output     .= "<input name='group". $row2['id'] ."' type='radio' id='". $row2['answer_id'] ."' />";
            $output     .= "<label for='". $row2['answer_id'] ."'>".$row2['answer_text']."</label>";
            $output     .= "<br>";              
        }

    }
    echo $output;
```

Comment: @Fred-ii-     :-(      Lateness sure has a Price ;-)

Comment: Naa better a good answer than a Fastest Gun In the West answer. If its good it will get UV's anyway

Comment: @RiggsFolly  It's not about a good or bad  answer or UV's. The answer chosen by OP is perfect.... the rests don't count though....